# Add multi-page watermark to PDF

Tags: pdfbox

I have [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZEmhni5QXv0dSU-E3MypipPcw5QzAW-t) merged PDF with [*Acroform*](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/pdf_forms_and_documents.html#Acroforms) only.

And I want add watermark to it.

> I add watermark_1.pdf to page 1,3,5
>
> I add watermark_2.pdf to page 2,4,6

And it works well with this code:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));

HashMap<Integer, String> overlayGuide = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); i = i + 2) {
    overlayGuide.put(i + 1, FOLDER + "watermark_1.pdf");
    overlayGuide.put(i + 2, FOLDER + "watermark_2.pdf");
}

Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
overlay.setInputPDF(doc);
overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
overlay.overlay(overlayGuide);

doc.save(new File(filePath));
```

But this way force me to separate my watermark into two file while my original watermark is into one file [see watermark_2pages.pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AR8ikwpuKkOBaLJsuk9YQ7fvrKXB33NH).

My question is it possible to configure overlay of PDFBox and use **watermark_2pages.pdf.pdf** and apply it to page 1 and 2 of my form directly (i.e. without having two watermark PDF file)?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to create such a map, you can simply use `setOddPageOverlayFile` and `setEvenPageOverlayFile` and use an empty map...

Comment: @mkl thank you, this is not my question. Yes here i can use even and odd but sometimes I can have watermark about 4 pages.... that's why  I need oberlayGuide, the original question is : how can I keep my watermark in one file and add in overlay for  page1 add watermark.pdf(page1) for page2 add watermark.pdf(page2) this is my issue. I want avoid separate my watermark in multiple files

Comment: Try `setAllPagesOverlayPDF` or `setAllPagesOverlayFile`, does this do what you want?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you it seems works but! without real exemple from you it not working before... because I didn't overlay.overlay:  `Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
  overlay.setInputPDF(merge);
  overlay.setAllPagesOverlayFile(FOLDER+"FR001FXX.pdf");
  overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.BACKGROUND);
  Map<Integer, String> overlaymap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();            
  overlay.overlay(overlaymap);` do I really need this overlay.overlay even with empty map

Comment: You wrote "it seems works" and "without real exemple from you it not working before" - so does it work or not? From a look at the source code you must pass an empty map, not null. If you pass null you'll get an NPE.

Comment: Exactly! It works when passing empty map object, i wonder why i need this

Comment: Because there is no other method, obviously :-) I suggest you answer the question yourself, I didn't really put much work into this. But I'll improve the documentation.